# Get location of an SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, location, skspritenode

I have an SKSpriteNode called "Laser" that is created in a method known as "shootLaser", with its scope being purely local to that method. The shootLaser method is called on a repeating timer, creating a new Laser object every couple of seconds, so I cannot simply declare the Laser object outside any method. I also have a variable known as laserLoc that I want to be always equal to the location of the "Laser" object at any given time.  In the update() method (which is called every time a frame is rendered), my idea was to set laserLoc = Laser.position, but since Laser is only local to the shootLaser method, I get a "use of unresolved identifier error". Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can declare an **SKSpriteNode** **Array** and add the Laser to it. Every time a new laser is created you can check that in your update func.

#### Here is an example:

```
class GameScene: SKScene{
var checkForNodes = [SKSpriteNode]()

func shootLaser {

/* Your stuff */
var Laser = SKSpriteNode()
checkForNodes.append(Laser)
}

override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    super.update(currentTime)
    
    
    for Laser in checkForNodes {

    /* Your Position Setup */  

    }
}
```

Comment: you unaccepted this question, could I help you somehow?! Did it not work for you? @Lahav